# When scanning a url/phone number qr code, is there anyway to force the iPhone to show 'Copy' menu only instead of asking opening browser?

Tags: iphone, camera, scanning

For example, when scan a url qr code with iPhone, the iPhone usually asks you to open browser with Safari (or ask you to dial a call if the qr code is a phone number), which is different from plain text that just ask you to search the context or copy the context.

My question is, is there anyway to force the iPhone to ask you to search the context or copy the context only, even if a url or phone number qr code is scanned?

Comment: see this https://discussions.apple.com/thread/250536998, it suggests using Shortcuts

Comment: I can verify the Shortcuts method works fine (on iOS 17.3.1) and is pretty easy to set up. In my case, Photos stubbornly refuses to give me a context menu that lets me copy the URL in the one case I've wanted to. I was going to add an answer suggesting that, but the link @Andra posted above works.

Answer (score -2):

It is possible to add spaces in your URL, for example instead of

`store.example.com`
use
`store. example. com`

Unfortunately, in such case in order to use the URL, it will be required to remove these spaces. But good side is that iOS camera will recognize QR code contents as the text, not the link.

Comment: Not sure how this helps for a QR code you scan somewhere.